# where do i find the wordpress "promote" class?

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a site using wordpress. I installed the 'starkers' theme and modified it. However, inside the  of the single.php, there's a bunch of text promoting the blog. This is enclosed within a  class of promote. I have been searching for where this text is located throughout my site but I cant seem to find it. I had initially thought that this was located within my functions.php, but the file is empty.

I was hoping someone here would be able to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops... sorry guys, i just found that the promote class was in a plugin that I created. It is not in the starkers theme. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a bit more specific information, like a link to the site in question? I downloaded a copy of the Starkers theme and did a quick `grep -ri promote .` and it seems that there's no "promote" class innate to the theme.

Comment: It seems like the class might be somewhere in the actual wordpress folder. I'm currently testing the website at the moment on a MAMP server on my mac, so i wouldnt be able to provide a link. I see it when I click on a post from the index page and it takes me to the single.php file. Then its located just above the comments section and just below the content of the post.

Comment: I mean, I could easily give a CSS property of display: none to the .promote class, but I'm just sure theres a more ideal way to this content entirely from the site.

Comment: I can't find the classname "promote" anywhere in vanilla Wordpress either. Try using grep to find what file is adding it. Open up the terminal and trying running this commmand:

grep -ri 'promote' /path/to/wordpress/directory